# Error using traits class.: "expected constructor destructor or type conversion before '&' token"

Tags: c++, stl, traits

I have a traits class that's used for printing out different character types:

```
template <typename T>
class traits {
public:
    static std::basic_ostream<T>& tout;
};
template<>
std::ostream& traits<char>::tout = std::cout;
template<>
std::wostream& traits<unsigned short>::tout = std::wcout;
```

gcc (g++) version 3.4.5 (yes somewhat old) is throwing an error:
"expected constructor destructor or type conversion before '&' token"

And I'm wondering if there's a good way to resolve this.

(it's also angry about _O_WTEXT so if anyone's got some insight into that, I'd also appreciate it)

Comment: Which platform are you using? On non-Windows platforms, `wchar_t` definitely is not synonymous to `unsigned short`. Not that this has any bearing to the problem you're facing, of course. :-P

Comment: Ah yes - I am in fact using a Windows machine.  I am aware that on other architectures, wchar_t may have more/fewer bytes.

Comment: it's not about the size. It's about the type identity.

Answer (score 1):

`wchar_t` is a different type than `unsigned short`. You have to use

```
template<>
std::wostream& traits<wchar_t>::tout = std::wcout;
```

Even though they may use the same representation, they are nontheless different integer types. Much like the three of `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`.

Also be sure you included the correct header (`<ostream>` or include `<iostream>`).